# How to say "Throw something at someone"

Tags: grammar

Particularly, I was wondering how to say "She threw cards at us" (as in playing cards). Is “她掷卡片对我们“ correct？

Comment: deal cards:发牌, for more card dealing terms see iciba,bkrs: 

It's your deal, ie your turn to deal the cards.

该你发牌了.

3.

I will deal the cards for the next five hands.

我将发下一轮五张牌.玩牌时，将手中的牌分发出去|你得先洗牌，然后再倒牌和发牌。You have to shuffle the cards before the cut for deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw something at somebody:把(东西)扔向（某人）。
She threw cards at us:
她把卡片扔向我们/她把卡片扔给我们/她朝我们扔卡片/她向我们扔来卡片

However, If playing cards, We don't say it like above. I think we just say "她向我们打出xx牌".
Playing cards: 打牌/打扑克Playing poker